# Call to a member function named() on array

Tags: laravel, lumen

When I want to match the current route in the controller, I use the $request->routeIs('user/*') method.

In the lumen Request class:
[Request class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdDbU.png)

But it is wrong：

```
   >(1/1) FatalThrowableError
   Call to a member function named() on array
   in Request.php line 204
   at Request->routeIs('user/*')
   in AuthServiceProvider.php line 38
```

How to use route matching (lumen5.6)

Comment: can you add some more details?

Comment: Show the code in which you are getting error.

Comment: code：$request->routeIs('user/*')